# How to select the employee who made the most sales

Tags: t-sql

I'm having trouble with this question in my Database homework.

I need to answer this question:

> Select the name of the Employee and the email address for the employee
>   that has the highest individual sale for the current month.

So I basically need to select the employee with the most sales for the current month.

And here's what I have:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName as 'Employee Name', Email 
FROM 
    Employee 
INNER JOIN 
    Sale ON Employee.EmployeeNumber = Sale.EmployeeNumber
GROUP BY 
    Sale.SaleDate, Sale.SaleNumber, Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Employee.Email
HAVING 
    DatePart(Month, SaleDate) = DatePart(Month, GetDate()) AND ...
```

The only thing I'm missing is the second part of my `HAVING` statement.

The query I currently have returns these [current query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTKlJ.png)

These results show me all sales made in the current month (November), we can see that Tom Tucker has the most sales. However, I need my select query to display his name only legitimately. (So without using WHERE (FirstName + LastName) = 'TomTucker')

I originally thought of using Max(Count(SaleNumber)) however I get an error saying I can't use aggregate functions within each other. So I have no clue how to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem break it into parts

Get the largest sale this month:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sale
WHERE DatePart(Month, SaleDate) = DatePart(Month, GetDate())
ORDER BY amt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Join to the user table.

```
SELECT COALESCE(E.FirstName+' '+E.LastName,E.FirstName,E.LastName,'') as Employee_Name, E.Email 
FROM Employee E
JOIN (
  SELECT EmployeeNumber
  FROM Sale
  WHERE DatePart(Month, SaleDate) = DatePart(Month, GetDate())
  ORDER BY amt DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) On S.EmployeeNumber  = E.EmployeeNumber
```

---

We can use the same technique to solve many problems to find the details of the employee with the most sales we just replace the inner query with this

```
-- select employee# with most sales this month
SELECT EmployeeNumber 
FROM (
  SELECT EmployeeNumber, Count(SaleNumber) as SC
  FROM Sale
  WHERE DatePart(Month, SaleDate) = DatePart(Month, GetDate())
) sub
ORDER BY SC DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Very intelligent, however you're grabbing the largest sale made in the current month. I'm looking for the employee who's made the most sales this month. Monetary value of the sale does not matter in this question. Thank you for taking the time to answer anyways though! :) I never knew about FETCH until now

Comment: @PierreGravelle - This is a quote from your question - "for the employee that has the highest individual sale for the current month."

Comment: @PierreGravelle - That is the quote from your question.  That is what I solved.

Comment: Thank you. I probably just misunderstood the wording in the question.

Comment: @PierreGravell -- because I'm in a good mood I'll show you how to do the other thing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at both ways to see if I understand them or not. I didn't understand COALESCE until I googled it in Microsoft's help documents.